# Access an array in windows form from another file in a solution

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, button, namespaces

I made a windows form application .sln in VS.  It has a Program.cs, and Form1.cs.  It builds.  There's a button  in Form1.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("Hello");}
```

I have an array in Program.cs

```
static void Main() {
string[] john = {"tom", "susan"};
}
```

I want my button to access this array so it can

```
MessageBox.Show(john[0]);
```

I don't understand all the namespaces and fully qualified classes and all that.  I just couldn't stick my array in Form1.cs anywhere without getting an error, it had to go back in Main.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I want to get rid of my error - "The name 'john' does not exist in the current context."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope of your variable limited to main method, do as below

```
static class Program
{
   public static string[] john = { "tom", "susan" };

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
```

and then

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Program.john[0]);
}
```

you can use public array declaration but you need to create instance of class in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the declaration of your variable john inside the form class, it should work.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        string[] john = { "tom", "susan" };

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Rest of your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is out of scope in Form1 class. To rectify declare it public in Program:

```
public static string[] john = {"tom", "susan"};
```

Then access with:

```
MessageBox.Show(Program.john[0]);
```

Comment: this wont compile. you have to create object of Progarm to access its non-static member.

Comment: Ok, I understand this one the best from my level of experience.  I had to move the array out of Main and add your changes. `namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {static class Program {public static string[] john = {"tom", "susan"}; [STAThread] static void Main() {}`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the array in `Form1` class for your form controls to use it. As a rule of thumb, don't put properties in `Program.cs` as they would be "too much global", or in other words, limit the scope of variable to the absolute bare minimum for cleaner and clearer code.

```
public class Form1
{
    string[] john = {"tom", "susan"};

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.john[0]);
    }
}
```

For more info, MSDN can help: [Access Modifiers (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) also you might want to take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787035/coding-guidelines-best-practices) regarding best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Make your array `public static`.

```
public static string[] john = {"tom", "susan"};

MessageBox.Show(Program.john[0]);
```

However, this is not to be considered as a good practice: `Form1` should not reference members of `Program` because it introduces a circular dependency (`Program` -> `Forms1` -> `Program`) and breaks encapsulation.

A better solution would be to store this list in a public property of `Form1`.